# Tikz: Constructing a right-angle triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (A) at (-3, -3);

    \draw (O) node[right] {$O$} --(A) node[right] {$A$};
    \draw (A)--++(110:3) coordinate (X);
    \draw[red] (O)--($(X)!(O)!(A)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

**Question**

Suppose I have the coordinates (O) and (A). Further suppose I know the direction of the line starting from (A), to which I will draw a perpendicular line from (O). In the code above, I just chose and arbitrary value, enough to construct the diagram.

Is there a Tikz-way to draw the line from (A) just to the point of intersection?

Comment: For a deeper understanding, read Chapter 4 of the manual, Tutorial: Euclid’s Amber Version of the Elements: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (A) at (-3, -3);

    \draw (O) node[right] {$O$} --(A) node[right] {$A$};
    \path[overlay] (A) --++ (110:1) coordinate (X);% invisible line
    \draw[red] (O) -- ($(X)!(O)!(A)$) coordinate (B);% added new coordinate B
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) node [left] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: `\path[overlay]`, so that the bounding box isn't affected.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you to point me to this option. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT What is bounding box being affected?

Comment: @blackened Try setting `border=0cm` for the class, and then change to e.g. `++ (110:5)` in the invisible path (without `overlay`). You'll see that there is some additional whitespace in the `tikzpicture`. That is because the `\path` affects the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`, the rectangle which decides how much space it takes up on the page, even if it is not actually drawn. The `overlay` options means that the path is not considered when the bounding box is calculated.